# Bracket for IF statement in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I know this is such a silly question but I tried every bracket I can think of to wrap the IF statement but it seems that none of them work.

For example:

```
IF(@item!=0){

   //Do stub
   RETURN   // without the brakets , this return does not belong to if
 }

   //Do some stubs  // and if the condition of the IF is false, this statement can't be reached
```

Thank you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try begin and end instead

```
IF(@item!=0)
begin
/*Do stub*/
RETURN   
/* without the brakets , this return does not belong to if  */
end
```

Comment: What if I want to nest two update statements inside an If? For example, would this work: 
`IF (condition) 
BEGIN
     BEGIN
          update-code
     END
     BEGIN
          update-code2
     END
END`

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `RETURN`, you can also use `ELSE`:

```
if @item != 0
begin
   -- Do stub
end
else
begin
    -- Do some stubs  
    -- and if the condition of the IF is false, this statement can't be reached
end
```

Plus:

- you don't need the brackets around the `IF` clause
- you have to use `--` instead of `//` for comments (see my example)